# C# Server, Android Java Client - Connection issues

Tags: java, c#, android, tcp

I'm currently working on a University project in which we send data from an Arduino to a C# server (works already), which then uses TCP to pass on the info to an Android app with a java client running on it. Unfortunately, the latter is not quite working yet. I can already establish a connection between client and server and send a message from the virtual phone (Android Studio) to the Server, but not the other way around. I am farely unexperienced with java, so every bit of help is highly appreciated!

I've attached the code below:

**C# Server:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SocketServer
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Parallel.Invoke
        (
            () => Arduino(),
            () => Android()
        );
    }


    public static void Arduino()
    {
        //Removed since unnecessary for question
    }

    public static void Android()
    {
        StreamReader streamReader_App;
        NetworkStream networkStream_App;

        TcpListener tcpListener_App = new TcpListener(1010);
        tcpListener_App.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("The Server has started on port 1010");

        int msg;

        while (true)
        {
            Socket serverSocket_App = tcpListener_App.AcceptSocket();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("App-Client connected");
                networkStream_App = new NetworkStream(serverSocket_App);

                streamReader_App = new StreamReader(networkStream_App);
                msg = 0;

                while (msg == 0)
                {
                    var line_App = streamReader_App.ReadLine();
                    if (line_App == "CoordRequest")
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        Console.WriteLine(line_App);
                        //Send coordinates to App
                        string message = "Test";
                        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message+"\r\n");
                        networkStream_App.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        bytes = new byte[1024];
                        msg = 1;
                    }
                }

                networkStream_App.Close();
                serverSocket_App.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Java Client (on Android) to start client and receive messages: MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tcpclient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText e1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyServerThread());
        myThread.start();
    }

    class MyServerThread implements Runnable
    {
        Socket s;
        ServerSocket ss;
        InputStreamReader isr;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        Handler h = new Handler();

        String message;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                ss = new ServerSocket(1010);
                while(true)
                {
                    s = ss.accept();
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void send(View v)
    {
        MessageSend messageSender = new MessageSend();
        messageSender.execute(e1.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

**Java Client (on Android) to send messages: MessageSend.java**

```
package com.example.tcpclient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MessageSend extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    PrintWriter pw;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {

        String message = voids[0];
        try
        {
            s = new Socket("192.168.1.10",1010);
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pw.write(message);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            s.close();

        }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



        return null;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tcpclient">
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `Java Client (on Android):` AND `ss = new ServerSocket(1010);` ? A server socket? Your C# server has already a server socket i think (code difficult to read, but it looks that `new TcpListener(1010)` defines the server). How should that work? A client uses a clientsocket. A server a serversocket.

Comment: Anyhow. `if (line_App == "CoordRequest")` The c# 'server'is waiting for the client sending a line with 'CoordRequest'. I dont see you sending that command in the 'client'.

Comment: `I can already establish a connection between client and server `. Who of the two  initiates the connection?

Comment: `and send a message from the virtual phone (Android Studio) to the Server,` Do you mean from your Android 'client' to the C# server? Which message exactly? And where in the server code is that message received?

Comment: I have a different script for sending a message from the client to the server, which I haven't shown, since it's already working. In other words, "CoordRequest" acts as a test command which, if the server receives it, should result in it passing on the String "Test". The server already receives messages from the client successfully, but the client doesn't receive the message "Test"

Comment: The client initiates the connection by sending a message you can type manually in a text box on the phone. I'll add the script to prevent confusion.

Comment: `The client initiates the connection by sending a message ` . No. A client can only send a message if the connection is established or initiated as you wich. You schould first be connected before you can send or receive messages. Who is establishing the connection? You are not even reacting on my serversocket remarks.

Comment: Your whole setup is unclear to me. Why does your Android client use/need a serversocket and a client socket?

Comment: I used a tutorial ("youtube.com/watch?v=29y4X65ZUwE") to create the android app. I didn't come up with the code myself. As already mentioned, I'm not very experienced with java, therefore, I have a hard time explaining how the code works exactly and how to use every command. Hence, why I didn't answer the serversocket question. I hope you understand. If you have a better solution, I'd be pleased to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You were using a Socket to listen to Tcp Client at
`Socket serverSocket_App = tcpListener_App.AcceptSocket();`

Follow the below code to correct your code

```
public static void Android()
{
    NetworkStream networkStream_App;

    // Buffer reader
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    string data = null;

    int port = 1010;

    //Replace IP with the IP of your C# server
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.43.153");

    TcpListener tcpListener_App = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
    tcpListener_App.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("The Server has started on port 1010");

    int msg;

    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = tcpListener_App.AcceptTcpClient();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App-Client connected");
            networkStream_App = client.GetStream();

            while ((msg = networkStream_App.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                // Get data 
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, msg);
                if (data.Equals("CoordRequest"))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    //Send coordinates to App
                    string message = "Test";
                    byte[] msgToClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + "\r\n");
                    networkStream_App.Write(msgToClient, 0, msgToClient.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }

            networkStream_App.Close();
            tcpListener_App.Stop();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your help and the time put into your answer! Unfortunately, I still don't receive a message on Android nor do I even receive any type of signal. Your answer still helped me clean up my code, so thank you for that as well!

Comment: Try to check Android network permission on your manifest. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`. Also try to check your C# server firewalls if the listening port is allowed in the firewalls rule or simply turn-off firewalls. It's Strange I used most of your code with the correction code above and received the signals and message.

Comment: I've added the second permission and turned my firewall off, unfortunately, still without any success. Did you also use the Android Studio emulator? I appreciate your help!